# Upgrading Firebase: "Unable to load your database"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I migrated my projects to the "new" Firebase via google.com. When I try to access my project database, I get only "Unable to load your database." I'm also making an assumption here that the "realtime database" replaces the old Dashboard where I can see data being added or removed from Firebase by my app.

There is no explanation whatsoever beyond the above message. Yet I know there is accessible data there because the listeners in my app continue to respond to it. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe contact Firebase directly - you get 5 fee tech questions per account. Scroll to the bottom of this page https://firebase.google.com/support/, contact us > technical support

Comment: According to the discussion on [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html) - this was a common error during the launch - you are encouraged to try again and it the problem persists you should file a ticket with the support team at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Also try to hard refresh the page. I noticed that the session for the database sometimes expires, while the rest of the Console keeps working.

Answer (score 48):

Fixed it!

Signed out from my Google account and logged in again.

Comment: I think it is not "Google programmers", but "Firebase Team programmers".

Comment: This worked for me. 
As an advice, do this if you have different google accounts logged in:
Had only the option to sing out from all my accounts, so I just switched between one of them and went back to the one with the Firebase project.

Comment: if you have more than one google account just switch to another one then roll back, also works, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Another way: open the console (F12) in the browser and run `localStorage.clear()`

Comment: Upvoted because it helped me to resolve my issue with the text editor for Firebase Realtime Database rules. I was trying to update the rules using the dashboard and the text editor always says unable to show result, please refresh. Found this post and this answer made me discover that there were a bunch of errors in the console and after some digging, turns out a CORS request did not succeed. Googled the error and guess what triggered the error? Adblocker.

Answer (score 1):

You have solved the problem and easily you should close the tab and reopen the home page in Firebase you have reload the firebase website or close than you web browser and reopen again but your have close all tab and reopen page in Firebase and open your project and see

Comment: Please do not include images as links when writing an answer.

Comment: ok now i am updated the my answer ok if you have solve problem my Facebook account :  https://www.facebook.com/abdullah.e.omer/ you can send message in this account

Comment: Refresh didn't work for me but closing and opening the pinned tab worked.

Comment: Yes This Is Correct, I told you this