# Unable to load your rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner in android  trying to set rules of database on my chatapp on Firebase. It gives me message unable to load your rule

[image]

Comment: answer says log out and try again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423673/upgrading-firebase-unable-to-load-your-database

Comment: i try it but nothing do.

Comment: 1. check internet connection in your system
2. validate your rules before upload

Comment: When I get this message, it is solved by a hard-refresh, or by signing out and in again. If that doesn't work for you, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: found any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Check your connectivity with server. Sign Out of Google and log in after a few minutes. It will be back to normal.

Fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378042/unable-to-load-your-database-firebase?answertab=active#tab-top)