# 'Unable to load your database' error in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I get the below error that my firebase database cannot be loaded. The database is connected to my Android app.

[image: unable to load your database]

Comment: logout and try login again this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly.

Comment: If logging out bothers you e.g. logs you outa devices and helluva google services, then just switching the account in firebase console will work too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firstly, Check your connectivity with server. Sign Out of Google and log in after a few minutes. It will be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Same solution given by @akhilesh0707.