# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR while making request to Firebase Realtime Database. Database was deleted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My web app I was currently developing, fetches a token (that I have stored in firebase) so it can get data from an api when the app first runs. And it's been working fine for weeks making requests back and forth no problem. Then suddenly it gives me a "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" when making that request. Checked the database everything looks fine, then in a couple of minutes it's suddenly emptied out/deleted. I cant even manually add anything. Tried a PUT request to add something, get that error for that too.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzRp.png)

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

I'm still new to development/first time using firebase.

Edit: You know I never added any rules to the database, and it had been 30 days I believe since I created it. Could that have been it? I was going to do it before deploying and thought I would finish before 30 days.

EDIT: Fixed it!

Okay so turns out I just needed to sign out of my other google accounts I was signed in.

With no answers, I had decided just to start a new firebase project, but then that one also didn't work but it said "unable to load your database" which led me to this [Upgrading Firebase: "Unable to load your database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423673/upgrading-firebase-unable-to-load-your-database)

Comment: Have you tried using another device with a different ISP? Can you share a screenshot of error itself?

Comment: Yes I've uploaded a screenshot of the console log. Doubt it would be much help. And it's not deployed yet, and I don't have another device or a different ISP I could try to use no.